# Access not granted to camera and microphone - Kurento Room demo

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am trying to run the Kurento Room demo application.

```
$ docker run --name kms -p 8888:8888 -d kurento/kurento-media-server
$ git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-room.git
$ cd kurento-room
# checkout the latest tag
$ git checkout $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
$ cd kurento-room-demo
$ mvn compile exec:java
```

I have already enabled camera/microphone access in browser. And this application was working fine few days back.
Now when I try to start the application it returns the following error "Access not granted to camera and microphone".

Any possible causes for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Is your application using `getUserMedia()` function?

Comment: Yes- ref: https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-room/blob/master/kurento-room-client-js/src/main/resources/static/js/KurentoRoom.js#L651

Comment: What browser are you using. Because this function is depreciated and in major updates of different browsers, the function is not working.